# How to add opencv2/face.hpp to ceemple (or to regular opencv)?

Tags: c++, opencv

i've been having an issue lately with opencv.
 I'm trying to make a c++ program that does face recognition. I was following [this tutorial](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/contrib/doc/facerec/tutorial/facerec_video_recognition.html), and using Netbeans 8, and opencv 2.4 and later 3.0, but it's no use, i can't add either face.hpp, nor contrib.hpp.

Then, following the advice of a friend, i switched to Visual studio 2013 and installed with it Ceemple, an opencv plugin, but yet it's no use, it doesn't seem that this face.hpp exists.

Is there a way to add it, either to opencv, or ceemple ?

Answer (score 0):

It is part of [opencv_contrib](https://github.com/Itseez/opencv_contrib), you must intall it